# Why rate of convergence is studied?

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, euler-mascheroni-constant

There are lots of papers on the Internet about sequences with different rates of convergence towards Euler's constant and every year more are published for better rates of convergence. Why is having sequences with better rates of convergence for Euler's constant is important? Is it relevant to proving its irrationality, and if so, how? By reading their papers, I couldn't find the reason why many people spend time on this subject, especially for one specific constant. Any ideas?

An example: https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13660-018-1670-6

Comment: From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#:~:text=In%20practice%2C%20the%20rate%20and,to%20yield%20a%20useful%20approximation:, In practice, the rate and order of convergence provide useful insights when using iterative methods for calculating numerical approximations. If the order of convergence is higher, then typically fewer iterations are necessary to yield a useful approximation. Also, maybe this adds insights: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462013/why-is-the-convergence-rate-important

Comment: Maybe, one wants to improve the evidence of the conjecture that the Euler-Mascheroni constant is irrational (it is even conjectured to be transcendental). The more digits we have, the better this evidence. Strangely , for memory challenges , $\pi$ and ONLY $\pi$ is used.

Comment: Euler's constant, and pi, and so on, are used only as test cases for numerical algorithms that have broader potential applications.

Comment: Supppose both $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge to $\gamma$, but $b_n$'s rate of convergence is faster than that of $a_n$. Then for large $n$, one would expect $|b_n-\gamma|<|a_n-\gamma|$, so $b_n$ becomes a better candidate for numerical approximating $\gamma$.

Comment: I believe people study this because it's fun.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why rate of convergence is studied is because it helps to calculate numbers (such as Euler's constant, in your case) very quickly. This way computers could give many digits of a given number in a short amount of time.

For example, it is known that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\pi$$ Although the summand seems simple, the series converges extremely slowly. But the Chudnovsky algorithm (I don't have enough time to write it down), although looks more complicated, could calculate $\pi$ way more quickly.